# (Unity) Aws SNS(Push Notification) Class not found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am trying to get the push notifications to work from amazon AWS simple notifications services and unity using their AmazonAWS SDK. I've been following the setup guide linked [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/sns.html). but when I tried to build the sample scene provided with the sdk I get this error on my phone.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcEbz.png)

I did put google-play-services.jar and android support.jar inside the Assets\plugins\android folder but for some reason its not able to find the GCM class. Could you please tell me as of what I might be doing wrong?

Error :
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/googlecloudmessaging;

caused by java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.google.android.gms.gcm.googlecloudmessaging

(I screen shot it from the logscreen on my phone there is no way to copy the whole error message.)

Comment: Post the error code instead of the image

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of digging I found the another jar file of play sevices , turns out the one I was using didnt have the reference to the GCM class